# How to use associate Search Center with Search Box?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, my-site, enterprise-search

I am setting up a "My Site Host" site collection, and want users to be able to add a Search Box web part which defaults to using our Enterprise Search Center site collection. First - is this possible? I have tried to link these using in the My Site site collection's Site Settings, but I haven't succeeded. If this is possible, any pointers are appreciated - thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a search center for all My Sites in the User Profiles Service Application > Setup My Sites > Preferred Search Center. Are the OOTB search box not working out?

**Be sure to add "/pages/" after the URL to your search-center.** As the example under the text box states.

[image]

There is currently a bug in SP2013, that by my understandings won't let you change the search center from the UI. The solution would be to do it with powershell instead.

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "Search Service Application name goes here"
$ssa.SearchCenterUrl = "http://url/site/searchcentername/Pages/"
$ssa.Update()
```

After the change you would still see the wrong URL in the Preferred Search Center but if you try to search, you will see that the change was made.

[Unable to change "Preferred search center" in My Site Settings](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/b88b0672-659b-471e-b489-cb6ef047fead/unable-to-change-preferred-search-center-in-my-site-settings?forum=sharepointgeneral)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did have that set up correctly already, but no luck.  What happens is, I search using the added Search Box web part. It takes me to the Search Center, but I get a "Page not found" error.  The URL in the browser at that point is **http://portal.company.com/sites/search/Pages/PageNotFoundError.aspx?requestUrl=http://portal.company.com/sites/search/results.aspx**.  I have **http://portal.company.com/sites/search** in the above-mentioned "Preferred Search Center" field on the "My Site Settings" page.

Comment: Did some more testing - I cannot modify the value of **Preferred Search Center** at all, and I am logged in as the farm admin. Odd.

Comment: I updated my answer. :)

Comment: I updated the Global Search Center URL, adding `/Pages`, and when I went back to "My Site Settings", the change was already reflected there.  I updated my site collection admin Search Settings with the added `/Pages`, did an `iisreset`, and things are working yay