# Modify Global Search Center URL

Tags: search, administration, global-navigation

I unfortunately did not add /pages to my url, so the search function doesn't work for me. I couldn't find a way to do it without using a powershell terminal. The solution that I found was this :

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$ssa.SearchCenterUrl = <newURL>
$ssa.Update()
```

The problem is that this command doesn't run in my powershell.

```
The term Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication is not recognized as 
the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
```

I have admin rights from that account in all the servers.

Comment: Have you added the sharepoint cmdlets? add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell

Comment: The SharePoint PowerShell snapin is installed with the SharePoint installation. The cmdlets can only be run on a SharePoint server and target the farm that the server is connected (so you cannot use the cmdlets to control another farm that the server is not a part of). I am running commands on the server.

Comment: You need to run the script from the sharepoint server where your search application is running on, should be the same server where your central admin is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that i answered the same question here: [How to use associate Search Center with Search Box?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98906/how-to-use-associate-search-center-with-search-box/98935#98935)

However, make sure to run powershell as admin, and add the sharepoint cmdlets by typing `add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell` before trying to update the search center. Make sure that you run the command from the server where Central admin is running. If you only got one application server, that's the one.

To clear things up a little bit:

1. Log into your server where central admin is running.
2. Open up and run PowerShell ISE as an administrator.
3. Type `Add-pssnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell`. Execute.
4. Type Get-spserviceapplication | ft typename . This will return the name of all your service applications. Look for name of your search application.
5. Copy the name of your search application, for example "Search Service Application"
6. Copy the code into the script panel. ( ctrl + r ) if it's missing.
7. Execute the script.

Example:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication "Search Service Application"
$ssa.SearchCenterUrl = "http://url/site/searchcentername/Pages/"
$ssa.Update()
```

On the other hand you should be able to just update your preferred search center from the search application page in central admin.

To do it from central admin, open central admin, click *Application Management*, then *manage service applications*, and then click on your *search service application* and click the URL from Global Search Center URL.

[image]

Comment: IT doesn't work 
Error : "Get -SPEnterpriseSearchServiceAlllication : SearchApplication service not found "

Comment: If you only run Get-spserviceapplication | ft typename you should get the name of your search service application.

Comment: I am using SP 2013 so I suppose it is installed along with sharepoint. Windows 2012 r2 server. It just returns the error not the name of the server.

Comment: You should try to update your search url from central admin instead. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Did you solve it? :)

Comment: The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. Verify that the administration component 'aa9dc70b-63e4-41c8-bce8-b1693e26d41e' in search application 'Search Service Application' is in a good state and try again.

Comment: Unfortunately it was not successful, the name is exact as the name that you provided, the link that I used is an enterprise search site collection with pages extension at the end , but is not working

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your Search, try this: http://blogs.technet.com/b/poojk/archive/2011/11/28/sharepoint-2010-search-service-is-not-able-to-connect-to-administration-component-server.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Your PowerShell cannot find the cmdlet 'Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication'. You either need to reference the Sharepoint.PowerShell namespace before you call the cmdlet or use the SharePoint Management Shell.

```
Add-PSSnapin -Name Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$ssa.SearchCenterUrl = <newURL>
$ssa.Update()
```

Comment: I do not get an error in the first two lines,nor any message.
In the third line i get the error "the < operator is reserved for future use"

Comment: That's because of the parameter -ErrorAction -SilentlyContinue that tells Powershell to finish even if there's errors. That's why you don't get anything.

Comment: Look at the link user19952 posted. And try leaving out the '-Error SilentyContinue' argument.

Comment: <newurl> should be replaced with the URL of the search center you're looking to use. Don't enter <newurl> verbatim.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your Search Service Application page and NEED TO UPDATE AN INCORRECT GLOBAL SEARCH CENTER URL, it looks like it is not updatable from this page, but actually it is!
You do not need to use PowerShell, if you are a Farm Admin, you can update the URL in that page.
***If you click on the incorrect Search Center link, it gives you a dialog where you can update the URL.***
(Poor UI design Microsoft, page design makes it look like you can't update it, but you can).