# SharePoint 2013 - Global Search Center URL not working

Tags: 2013, search

We tried to set the Global Search Center URL in Cental Admin -> Search Servcie Application but it seems not working. We tried to set it by PowerShell script and do an IISREST but when do a search within a site, it is still goes to _layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx

Answer (score 2):

This does it:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$ssa.SearchCenterUrl = "$SearchSiteURL" #which ends /pages
$ssa.Update()
```

No Site Collection settings need to be updated - only if it should display on a different search center.

Answer (score 1):

How does the URL you tried to set in Central administration look like? Did you add the mandatory `"/Pages/"` to your preferred search center URL? This is the most common miss. Don't forget to update the User Profiles / Mysites search center URL after.

Oh, and after this is done, you have to specify in every site collection that the query should be redirected to the global search center. Log into the site collection as a site collection administrator and follow this steps:

> Specify search settings for a site collection
>
> In your site collection, go to Settings, click Site settings and then
>   under Site Collection Administration, click Search Settings.
>
> To specify a Search Center, in the Search Center URL box, type the URL
>   of the Search Center site.
>
> To change which search result page queries are sent to, in the section
>   Which search results page should queries be sent to?, clear Use the
>   same results page settings as my parent, and then select one of the
>   following:
>
> Send queries to a custom results page URL.  Enter the URL. Custom URLs
>   can be relative or absolute, and can also include special tokens, such
>   as {SearchCenterURL}.  Example: `/SearchCenter/Pages/results.aspx` or
>   `http://server/sites/SearchCenter/Pages/results.aspx`.
>
> Turn on the drop-down menu inside the search box, and use the first
>   Search Navigation node as the destination results page. If you choose
>   this option, users can choose search vertical in the search box when
>   they enter a query.
>
> Click OK.

I've answered this question before, take a look at this two threads to get some more information.

[Modify Global Search Center URL](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/105282/modify-global-search-center-url/105284#105284)

[How to use associate Search Center with Search Box?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98906/how-to-use-associate-search-center-with-search-box/98935#98935)

[Specify search settings for a site collection or a site](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Specify-search-settings-for-a-site-collection-or-a-site-99da1d77-f42b-4f56-b48a-24e87f336e91)

Comment: Many thanks for your asnwers, user19952... I have "/Pages" in my URL.
I'm curious on why the Global Search Center URL is not wokring globally, still duplicate settings need to be done in every site collection. What I was initially thought was Site Search Setting inherit from Site Collection Search Setting, Site Collection Search Settging inherit from Global Settings in Search Service Application. But in this case, it seems not behavior like this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, that the global search center wasn't being picked up by the site collections when you specified a blank search center url in the site collection settings and had the "use the same results page settings as my parent" checked off. The way I've gotten this to work is by going to the pages library of the search center and setting the results.aspx page as the home page of the site.