# The search for user profile not showing any result ( sharepoint 2013 )

Tags: search, user-profile, search-results, user-accounts, mysite

When i am trying to search on my user from the team site (the small search box) i can't find the user profile in the result of search
it's showing only employees list and document but the profile there's no result

Comment: What version of SharePoint? Are you crawling the user profiles in any of your content sources? ( sps3://mysiteUrl for http / sps4://mysiteUrl for https)

Comment: sps3://mysite/ and http//mysite

Comment: And you do have a "people" result tab in your search result page?

Comment: no there's no people tab

Comment: Have you set up a site collection search center? A people tab will be included there that uses local people results. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582314.aspx

Comment: after create the enterprise search center i change the setting in my intranet by enter a search center URL and results page URL and now it's working, TU man

Comment: Great! Don't forget to associate the search center to your my site web application, take a look at this: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98906/how-to-use-associate-search-center-with-search-box/98935#98935

Comment: @user19952 sps3s:// is for https. I don't believe sps4:// is a valid protocol.

Answer (score 2):

After creating the Enterprise Search Center I changed the setting in my Intranet by entering a Search Center URL and results page URL and now it's working. Thx for user19952.